# "Class 'Illuminate\Http\Get' not found" in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm on working on Laravel 5.3 and got stuck with this error.

**author_page.blade.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/authors_detail',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '',
    success: function(data) {
        $('h1#author_page_url').html(data.bio[0].upload_pic)
        $('div#about_us').html(data.bio[0].aboutus_body)

    }
 });
});

</script>
```

**AjaxOperationController**

```
public function author_detail($id)
{
    $author_id= Get::findOrFail($id);
    echo "author detail". $author_id;
    $author_bio=DB::select('select * from author_profile where 
                                   author_id = ?', [$author_id]);
    return response()->json(array('bio'=>$author_bio),200);
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('author_page/{id}','AjaxOperationController@author_detail');
```

Comment: Try `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: already done bro!

Comment: Shouldn't you do `Author::findOrFail($id)` or whatever your author modal name is?